# How I can generate multiple entries in tkinter using loop?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

***I am using Python 2.7 and using tkinter to generate multiple entries using loops.... 
It only generates one entry...
Please Help.***

```
from Tkinter import *

top = Tk()

top.title('Software')

def button():

        top=Tk()

        for x in range(1,5):
            Label(top,text="Enter:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')
            Entry(top).grid(row=0,column=1,padx=2,pady=2,sticky='we',columnspan=9)
         return

Button(top, text="Next", command=button).grid(row=0, column=10, sticky='ew', padx=2, 
pady=2)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate Tkinter buttons dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236182/generate-tkinter-buttons-dynamically)

Comment: What makes you think it's only generating one? It looks like it is generating them just fine. It's just that you're putting them all in the same row and column so they are stacked on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

### Task 1: make it "generate multiple entries in tkinter using loop" work:

```
from Tkinter import *
top = Tk()
top.title('Loop works')
Button(    top, text = "Next"   ).grid( row = 0, column = 10, sticky = 'ew', \
                                                              padx   = 2,    \
                                                              pady   = 2     \
                                                              )
aProxy = []                               # .NEW <Stack> of Access Methods / Wrappers

for x in range( 1, 5 ):                   # for(){}-looper - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    aProxy.append( StringVar() )          # PUSH an Access Method / Wrapper on <Stack>
    aProxy[-1].set( str( -1 * x ) )       # .SET ( asString ) via an Access Method

    Label( top, text = "Enter:"           ).grid( row = x, column =  0, sticky = 'e' )
    Entry( top, textvariable = aProxy[-1] ).grid( row = x, column =  1, sticky = 'we', \
                                                                        padx   = 2,    \
                                                                        pady   = 2,    \
                                                                        columnspan = 9 
                                                                        )
    pass                                  # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
top.lift()                                # Tk-GUI-MVC-Visual-Part ensure visibility
top.mainloop()                            # Tk-GUI-MVC-Controller-Part Entry Point
```