# Basic methods & GUI assistance

Tags: python, user-interface, methods, tkinter

I'm completely new to programming and green if it comes to Python itself. I started learning a few days ago and I need some help understanding and making my code simpler. I'm working on a simple GUI, which I've created. Everything works just fine but I'm wondering how to mix the tkinter button widgets with the methods so I dont have to create different one every time I create a new widget. This should include variable values but this is quite hard for me to understand and that's why I've come here for help. Thanks for all the help ;D 
Here I'm posting the shortened version, original includes 10 buttons so you can imagine how crappy this looks

```
import Tkinter as tk



def __init__(master):
    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()

def toggle_text():

    if button["text"] == "WL":
        button["text"] = "WYL"
        label["bg"] = "green"


    else:
        button["text"] = "WL"
        label["bg"] = "red"


def toggle_text1():

    if button1["text"] == "WL":
        button1["text"] = "WYL"
        label1["bg"] = "green"

    else:
        button1["text"] = "WL"
        label1["bg"] = "red"

def toggle_text2():

    if button2["text"] == "WL":
        button2["text"] = "WYL"
        label2["bg"] = "green"

    else:
        button2["text"] = "WL"
        label2["bg"] = "red"



root = tk.Tk()
root.title("GUI - TEST")

button = tk.Button( text="WL", width=12, command=toggle_text, bg='red')
button.grid(row=0, column=1)
label = tk.Label(bg='red', width=6, text='1')
label.grid(row=0, column=2)

button1 = tk.Button( text="WL", width=12, command=toggle_text1, bg='red')
button1.grid(row=1, column=1)
label1 = tk.Label(bg='red', width=6, text='2')
label1.grid(row=1, column=2)

button2 = tk.Button( text="WL", width=12, command=toggle_text2, bg='red')
button2.grid(row=2, column=1)
label2 = tk.Label(bg='red', width=6, text='3')
label2.grid(row=2, column=2)



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way to do it is to define a short callback wrapper function with default arguments, which in turns calls the real event handler function with the arguments it needs. Here's an example based on your code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

NUM_BUTTONS = 3
button_list = []
label_list = []

def toggle_text(button_num):
    button = button_list[button_num]
    label = label_list[button_num]
    if button['text'] == 'WL':
        button['text'] = 'WYL'
        label['bg'] = 'green'
    else:
        button['text'] = 'WL'
        label['bg'] = 'red'

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('GUI - TEST')

for i in range(NUM_BUTTONS):  # create widgets
    def _wrapper(button_num=i):  # default argument value is current index
        toggle_text(button_num)

    button = tk.Button(text='WL', width=12, bg='red', command=_wrapper)
    button.grid(row=i, column=1)
    button_list.append(button)

    label = tk.Label(text=i+1, width=6, bg='red')
    label.grid(row=i, column=2)
    label_list.append(label)

root.mainloop()
```

In the code above, the text of each `tk.Label` is set via the `text=i+1` argument in the

```
label = tk.Label(text=i+1, width=6, bg='red')
```

statement. To give each label its own arbitrary text value, you could define another list containing the text for each label, for example:

```
label_text_list = ['L1', 'L2', 'L3', ...]
```

and then use

```
label = tk.Label(text=label_text_list[i], width=6, bg='red')
```

in the loop instead.

Also see [*Generate Tkinter buttons dynamically*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236182/generate-tkinter-buttons-dynamically) for another example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this clears things up a bit. But could you explain where does tkinter takes the button number value from? Because when I do it 'manually' I always assign different names to 'button' and I don't see how does Python manage to do that

Comment: I also cant figure out how use this code when creating labels manually with their own, different text values. Sorry for my lack of knowledge but I feel like that's the only way I can learn it

Comment: See updated answer where I've tried addressing your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making a class for your button, there are loads of tutorials on classes, here's one that really helped me:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trOZBgZ8F_c

Answer (score 0):

An object-oriented way to do what you want is to create a class that contains one or more GUI widgets and defines methods that operate upon them. The is considered a more advanced technique, but using it will make modifying and enhancing your program later easier.

For example, you could make the background color a variable rather than hardcoding it to be `'red'` by simply by adding another argument to the `__init__()` method and passing a value for it when creating instances.

The following does the same thing as your script (and my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29807368/355230)). The `tk.Button` in each instance of a `MyWidget` will call that instance's `__call__()` method when it's clicked due to the `command=self.__call__` argument used when the `Button` is created.

```
import Tkinter as tk

NUM_MY_WIDGETS = 3

class MyWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, row, column, label_text):
        self.button = tk.Button(text='WL', width=12, bg='red',
                                command=self.__call__)
        self.button.grid(row=row, column=column)

        self.label = tk.Label(text=label_text, width=6, bg='red')
        self.label.grid(row=row, column=column+1)

    def __call__(self):
        if self.button['text'] == 'WL':
            self.button['text'] = 'WYL'
            self.label['bg'] = 'green'
        else:
            self.button['text'] = 'WL'
            self.label['bg'] = 'red'

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('GUI - TEST')

widgets = []
for i in range(NUM_MY_WIDGETS):  # create widgets
    widgets.append(MyWidget(i, 1, i+1))

root.mainloop()
```