# Tkinter: When press 'Enter', then it goes to the next text box

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So my teacher told me to learn Tkinter be myself and I try to understand it.
Here's is the program I'm looking at.

It asks for a name and last name. (Yeah, Spanish is my native language)

When I finish inserting the name, I just want to press enter to go to the next text box which is last name.

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="Ingrese sus nombres: ").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Ingrese sus apellidos: ").grid(row=1)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

mainloop()
```

Comment: You're asking how to make 9 lines of code simpler? That's going to be tough!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick and dirty way would be to `bind` the first `Entry` widget to a function that switches the focus to the other widget:

```
def go_to_next_entry(event):
    e2.focus_set() # focus_set() switches the focus to the new widget

e1.bind('<Return>', go_to_next_entry)
# or, if you are familiar with lambdas, simply:
# e1.bind('<Return>', lambda e: e2.focus_set())
```

The [`.bind`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) method expects as a first argument a string representing the type of user interaction, and as a second argument, a *function* of a single argument (the event argument. In this case you do not have to care about that, but if you were monitoring the movement of the cursor, the event could give you its coordinates.)

---

For a more general way, things get trickier and this method seems more an hack than anything. Anyway, if you have many entries, you can automate the method like so:

1. Find all `Entry` widgets. They are children of `master` and you get them from `master.winfo_children()`, which gives the children in the order they were declared in the code. Be careful, though, because you get *all* the children (the `Labels`, too), so you have to filter the children (in this case the filter is "by type" and it is done with `isinstance`):

   ```
   entries = [child for child in master.winfo_children()
              if isinstance(child, Entry)]
   ```
2. Then, you define the function that switches the focus to the desired widget:

   ```
   def go_to_next_entry(event, entry_list, this_index):
       next_index = (this_index + 1) % len(entry_list)
       entry_list[next_index].focus_set()
   ```

   The part `next_index = (this_index + 1) % len(entries)` cycles over the entries (if you press <kbd>Return</kbd> at the last entry, you go to the first one).
3. Finally, you bind the switch function to each entry:

   ```
   for idx, entry in enumerate(entries):
       entry.bind('<Return>', lambda e, idx=idx: go_to_next_entry(e, entries, idx))
   ```

   The scary part is: `lambda e, idx=idx: go_to_next_entry(e, entries, idx)`. The important part here, is that `lambda` is used to create *another* function (much like `def`) that has 2 arguments instead of the 3 required by `go_to_next_entry`. The `idx=idx` part makes it possible to call the newly-created function with just 1 parameter (as required by `.bind`.) To see why `idx=idx` is actually important and could not be omitted, have a look at [Generate Tkinter buttons dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236182/generate-tkinter-buttons-dynamically) (which is about buttons, but the principle is the same.)

The complete code:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="Ingrese sus nombres: ").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Ingrese sus apellidos: ").grid(row=1)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)
e3 = Entry(master)
e4 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
e4.grid(row=3, column=1)

def go_to_next_entry(event, entry_list, this_index):
    next_index = (this_index + 1) % len(entry_list)
    entry_list[next_index].focus_set()

entries = [child for child in master.winfo_children() if isinstance(child, Entry)]
for idx, entry in enumerate(entries):
    entry.bind('<Return>', lambda e, idx=idx: go_to_next_entry(e, entries, idx))

mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you. What about using it in other lines? A more general function rather than only applying it for e2.

Answer (score 0):

I 've found one solution about that.

if we have  two entries like Entry_1 and Entry_2 then we want the cursor first stop in Entry_1 and when we press enter (or whatever we want  other than "Return" key) the cursor will pass to the Entry_2.

```
entry_1.focus() 
entry_1.bind("<Return>",lambda funct1:entry_2.focus())
```