# USB Barcode Scanner in python: Text Field Focus

Tags: python, tkinter, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am trying to read from USB barcode scanner into my application. I can read the barcode into the application since it is an input from a keyboard.

My question is, let's say I have two text fields, how can I set the focus transition from the first field into the second field once the input is scanned into the first field?

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

you can check to see if the first entry is empty and then switch focus to the second one

```
if len(the_first_entry_widget.get()) != 0:
   the_second_entry_widget.focus()
```

Answer (score 0):

Most scanners can add suffix code to the scanned barcode data for notification.
The most commonly used is the Enter(Carriage Return) key, but the Tab key may also be used.

You can do as follows.

- Using the setting barcode, it is set to inform that keys such as Enter(Tkinter's event name is Return), Tab etc. which are not normally included in the barcode as a suffix.
- Bind an event handler for the corresponding suffix key to the widget.
- In the event handler, move the focus to the next(or determined in some way) widget.

Please refer to the following.

[Change the focus from one Text widget to another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1450180/9014308)
[Tkinter: When press 'Enter', then it goes to the next text box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44638007/9014308)