# is there a way to jump from one entry field to another entry field in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to make billing software with multiple entries in python, so it's hard to move from one entry field to another entry field using a mouse, I just wanted it to jump from the customer name field to customer phone no entry was filed when I press "enter" key but it's not working how can I make it work

```
from Tkinter import*

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1350x700+0+0')
root.resizable(width=False,height=False)
root.title('Billing App')

def jump_cursor(event):
    customer_PhoneNo_entry.icursor(0)

customer_detail_frame=Frame(root,bd=10,highlightbackground="blue", highlightthickness=2)
customer_detail_frame.place(x=0,y=10,width=1350,height=100)

customer_detail_lbl=Label(customer_detail_frame,text="customer detail",font=('verdana',10,'bold'))
customer_detail_lbl.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=10,padx=20)

customer_name_lbl=Label(customer_detail_frame,text="customer name",font=('verdana',10,'bold'))
customer_name_lbl.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=10,padx=20)

customer_name_entry=Entry(customer_detail_frame,width=20,textvariable = Customer_Name)
customer_name_entry.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=10,padx=20)

customer_phoneno_lbl=Label(customer_detail_frame,text="phone no.",font=('verdana',10,'bold'))
customer_phoneno_lbl.grid(row=1,column=2,pady=10,padx=20)

customer_PhoneNo_entry=Entry(customer_detail_frame,width=20,textvariable = Customer_Ph_No)
customer_PhoneNo_entry.grid(row=1,column=3,pady=10,padx=20)
customer_PhoneNo_entry.bind("<Return>",jump_cursor)
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44638390/14465779) helped me with the same problem.

---

- First, get all children of `customer_detail_frame` which are `Entry`,
  using `winfo_children()`
- Second, bind each child to `<Return>`, (in which `lambda` can be used
  to create another function).
- Last, define the `jump_cursor` function, such that it switches the
  focus to the desired widget, using `focus_set()`.

Here is what changes in your code would look like:

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1350x700+0+0')
root.resizable(width=False,height=False)
root.title('Billing App')

Customer_Name, Customer_Ph_No = StringVar(), StringVar()

customer_detail_frame=Frame(root,bd=10,highlightbackground="blue", highlightthickness=2)
customer_detail_frame.place(x=0,y=10,width=1350,height=100)

customer_detail_lbl=Label(customer_detail_frame,text="customer detail",font=('verdana',10,'bold'))
customer_detail_lbl.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=10,padx=20)

customer_name_lbl=Label(customer_detail_frame,text="customer name",font=('verdana',10,'bold'))
customer_name_lbl.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=10,padx=20)

customer_name_entry=Entry(customer_detail_frame,width=20,textvariable = Customer_Name)
customer_name_entry.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=10,padx=20)

customer_phoneno_lbl=Label(customer_detail_frame,text="phone no.",font=('verdana',10,'bold'))
customer_phoneno_lbl.grid(row=1,column=2,pady=10,padx=20)

customer_PhoneNo_entry=Entry(customer_detail_frame,width=20,textvariable = Customer_Ph_No)
customer_PhoneNo_entry.grid(row=1,column=3,pady=10,padx=20)


def jump_cursor(event, entry_list, this_index):
    next_index = (this_index + 1) % len(entry_list)
    entry_list[next_index].focus_set()

entries = [child for child in customer_detail_frame.winfo_children() if isinstance(child, Entry)]
for idx, entry in enumerate(entries):
    entry.bind('<Return>', lambda e, idx=idx: jump_cursor(e, entries, idx))


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: why cant we directly put the ``` jump_cursor ( entries,idx)``` in place of the lambda function i have tired to do that but its not working when i directly put the jump_cursor function instead of lambda function

Comment: In the `lambda` function, there is an  `e` event that carries the information of when, where, and on what the `Return` key was pressed. This event object `e` is essential to tell the function `jump_cursor` on which event the key was pressed. The function `jump_cursor` is not just a simple function now; it is a "handler" function and requires a parameter for `event`. [Refer here for detail](https://python-course.eu/tkinter/events-and-binds-in-tkinter.php).