# how to define a series of buttons and run a function with a different input for each of them tkinter python

Tags: python, for-loop, button, tkinter

So I use a for-loop to define a series of buttons:

```
buy = [None] * 11
for x in range(11):
    buy[x] = Button(buyf, text = ProjectList[x][2],command= lambda: buycheck(x), bg = "red", fg = "white")
```

Why when I press any of the buttons do they just return the maximum value(11)?
I want each of the buttons to call the function *buycheck* with the input of the x value at the time of assignment of said button. Also, the buttons are put into a pre-sized array and then referenced on and off.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [Generate Tkinter buttons dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236182/generate-tkinter-buttons-dynamically), according to what you said (which is not completely clear) you're having some trouble using dynamic buttons.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `buycheck(x)` will always be executed with `x = 10` (value after the for loop).  You should pass x as default value of first argument of the lambda as below:

```
command=lambda n=x: buycheck(n)
```